# Disable textbox after switching between radio buttons

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have the following code. Is there's a smart way to disable textbox and clear his value after switching between the the radio buttons?

```
<div class="checkbox">
 <label style="margin-bottom:10px">Number of...:</label>
  <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:10px">
       <input class="radio" name="2" type="radio" checked="checked" id="numOfRadio" style="display:block;float:left">
       <input class="form-control" name="numOf" type="number" placeholder="1000" value="1000" id="numOf" style="width:140px"  />
       <label for="radio_2" style="font-weight:400"><input type="radio" name="2" id="radioAll" style="margin-left" />All</label>
  </div>      
</div>
```

I try to use the following code, but it didn't help:

```
$('.radio').on('click', function() {
    $('.radio')
        .siblings()
        .prop('disabled', true);

    $(this)
        .siblings()
        .prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: I added the code above.

Comment: @Omri Hi, check the edited answer by Rejith R Krishnan! Cheers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. The second `radio` is inside a label. So `siblings` is not enough. Get the parent `div` and use that to get to the `input` using `find`.

```js
$('.radio').on('change', function() {
  var val = this.id == 'radioAll' ? '' : 1000;
  $(this)
    .closest('div').find('input[type="number"]')
    .prop('disabled', this.id == 'radioAll')
    .val(val).attr("placeholder",val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label style="margin-bottom:10px;">Number of...:</label>
  <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <input class="radio" name="2" type="radio" checked="checked" id="numOfRadio" style="display:block;float:left">
    <input class="form-control" name="numOf" type="number" placeholder="1000" value="1000" id="numOf" style="width:140px" />
    <label for="radioAll" style="font-weight:400">
      <input class="radio" type="radio" name="2" id="radioAll" style="margin-left" />All
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and for clearing the form-contro:

$(".form-control").val(""); - clears the value
$(".form-control").removeAttr("placeholder"); clears the placeholder

Comment: @MrBuggy I cleaned up the answer a bit and added your condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this function to your .js file

```
function Disable() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('numOf');
    elem.disabled = true;
    elem.value="";
}
```

then call it in the event of onclick()

```
onclick="javascript:Disable()"
```